# Call to undefined function is_blog_installed(), after creating functions.php

Tags: fatal-error

I'd like to place some custom code in `functions.php` which I'm unable to do so. Why am I getting the following errors after the creation of (even an empty) `functions.php`? I'm using WP 5.4.2 with [Heroku-wp](https://github.com/xyu/heroku-wp)
?

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function is_blog_installed() in /app/public.built/wp-includes/load.php:606 Stack trace: #0 /app/public.built/wp-settings.php(161): wp_not_installed() #1 /app/public.built/wp-config.php(255): require_once('/app/public.bui...') #2 /app/public.built/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/app/public.bui...') #3 /app/public.built/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('/app/public.bui...') #4 /app/public.built/index.php(17): require('/app/public.bui...') #5 {main} thrown in /app/public.built/wp-includes/load.php on line 606

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_option() in /app/public.built/wp-includes/l10n.php:69 Stack trace: #0 /app/public.built/wp-includes/l10n.php(136): get_locale() #1 /app/public.built/wp-includes/l10n.php(756): determine_locale() #2 /app/public.built/wp-includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php(41): load_default_textdomain() #3 [internal function]: WP_Fatal_Error_Handler->handle() #4 {main} thrown in /app/public.built/wp-includes/l10n.php on line 69
```

I'm editing `public/wp-includes/functions.php` file, not the core one. It used to work.

Comment: Where did you put your new functions.php? In a theme or a plugin? Or did you overwrite the functions.php in WordPress's wp-includes? (which is where is_blog_installed() should be defined) You should put the original back and find somewhere else to add your new code - you shouldn't be editing the core WordPress files.

Comment: Question's been updated.

Comment: What's /public/? How does it relate to /public.built/, which I assume is core ? I'm nervous that it is overwriting the core file somehow since it's in a folder called wp-includes - do files in /public/ override /public.built/ somehow? Perhaps you need to explicitly include ../public.built/wp-includes/functions.php at the top of your file?

Comment: That's the folder where files get copied from at deploy time. Please have a look at the Heroku-wp github project. I have tried to explicitly include `functions.php` but got an even worse server error.

Comment: OK, I'd misunderstood how they were combined. In that case I still think that public/wp-includes/functions.php is wrong because that file will end up overwriting the file from core when they're combined into public.built. Put your code in a PHP file in public/wp-content/plugins instead - the name doesn't matter - or make a folder there and and call it functions.php.

Comment: To continue this and resolve deployment issues, you need to contact Heroku-WP official support, hosting issues are offtopic here. Just keep in mind the `wp-includes` folder is not to be modified, those are core WordPress files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm editing public/wp-includes/functions.php file, not the core one. It used to work.

Ths is your problem, ***never modify files in the `wp-includes` folder under any circumstances!***.

When tutorials and articles refer to `functions.php`, they're referring to the functions file in the current theme. This file does not always exist but you can create it.

I would recommend you create a child theme, to avoid your changes being lost when that theme is updated. You can also create a plugin by placing a PHP file in the `plugins` folder, and placing a command at the top with `/** Plugin Name: haxpanel's plugin **/` at the top. This will appear in the plugins list in the Admin dashboard for activation.

Before you do any of this though, fix your WP install by undoing the changes you made to `wp-includes`. Again, ***never*** modify the files of WordPress itself. The only time you should ever modify files in `wp-admin` or `wp-includes` is when you're helping develop new WordPress releases. For personal sites, client sites, commercial or enterprise development, it is unnecessary, and in a lot of cases dangerous to modify those folders. Do not touch!

Comment: I think the deployment mechanism is confusing things here: this is [heroku-wp](https://github.com/xyu/heroku-wp) on GitHub which appears to unpack a clean copy of WordPress into /public.built/ and then copy the files from /public/ over it. So OP's wp-includes/functions.php is a new file in an empty directory, it's just ending up overwriting a core file when the deployment is built.

Comment: That's a Heroku-WP problem, we aren't the Heroku-WP support vendor, but I can confirm that files iin `wp-includes` ARE the core files.

Comment: Thanks for the clear and detailed answer, that's worked!